# Reports goes blank if table not found

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I have a connection between the User table--(UserID to UserID)-- DealerAssigned(DealeID to DealerID)--Dealer Table

My report needs to show dealer info if the user is attached to a dealer. But if UserID is not founded in the DealerAssigned table, my reports goes blank. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I guess you have used inner join to the user id table try giving outer join and check

Answer (score 0):

Create logic to check if any data is returned. If no data is returned, display a message, such as:

> "No results were found for x.y.z."

Comment: I mean, like, if UserID is not founded - show other stuff(standart dealer info).

Comment: In that case you would check if a user id does not exist. If not then you will display the basic information, see below:

Something along the lines of
`if(!$user_id){
//Insert Standard dealer information
}`